# Add groups to a group (Active directory) Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am making an application to interact with Active Directory (list groups, add users to groups, etc). My problem is that I can not add a group to an existing group.
I use ActiveDs_TLB and adshlp.

This is the code I am trying to use to add the group.

```
var
grupo : IAdsGroup;
grup: IAdsGroup;
Rutagrupo: string;
begin
Rutagrupo := 'WinNT://domain/grupodestino';
AdsGetObject(Rutagrupo, IADsGroup, grupo);
grup := dom.GetObject('group', 'grupoagregar') as IAdsGroup;
grupo.Add(grup.ADsPath);
end;
```

When I run the code it sends me a message that says "The username was not found."

Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Comment: What would you like us to do? We can't see your AD memberships to see if the username/group  exists or not.

Comment: Hello,

For someone who might be interested in the solution. The code is well the topic is in the scope of the group in the Active Directory.

1- You can not add another group of the same scope to a group with global scope.
2- A global scope group can be added to a group with local domain scope.
3- Another group of the same domain can be added to a local domain scope group.

These restrictions are at the IADsGroup level, since the AD management tools can vary.

A greeting.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who might be interested in the solution. The code is well the topic is in the scope of the group in the Active Directory.

1- You can not add another group of the same scope to a group with global scope.
2- A global scope group can be added to a group with local domain scope.
3- Another group of the same domain can be added to a local domain scope group.

These restrictions are at the IADsGroup level, since the AD management tools can vary.

A greeting.